# Can I upgrade V-brake to disk brake for Cannondale Quick Cx 5

Tags: brakes

I have a Cannondale Quick Cx5 with V brake. 
I'm wondering whether I can upgrade to disk brake?

Comment: Off the top of my head, the two problems I'd foresee would be attaching the rotors to the wheels, and attaching the callipers to the fork/frame. If you can crack these you should be sorted.

Comment: Most frames that don't come with disk brakes don't have the necessary attachment points on the fork and rear stays to accommodate disk brakes. which is quite a shame, as it would probably cost them less than $10 in parts and labor, and would make it much easier to upgrade the bike later.

Comment: If the frame does not have lugs on the fork and rear stays to attach the calipers then it's highly impractical to change.  Otherwise it's simply impractical.

Comment: @Kibbee - But to supply a frame with disk lugs would mean the manufacturer would have to install a different, heavier, less flexible fork.

Comment: For the front you could up grade to a fork/shocks that take disc brake.